# Возможно ли в .Net убрать предупреждение выдаваемое компилятором на конкретную строку кода из общего списка?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, warning

Компилятор Visual Studio выдаёт предупреждения на различные "скрытые ошибки" по его мнению. В одних случаях, это действительно промахи и программист их устраняет. В других, программист хоть и согласен с умной машиной, но желает оставить код без изменений. Количество таких предупреждений может расти, и становится сложно заметить новые. Вопрос: "Существуют ли какие-нибудь атрибуты или другие способы убрать предупреждение из списка, который выдаётся при компиляции?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если это лишь предупреждения, их можно отключить так. Пусть коды ваших предупреждений 1234 и 9876 (можно подсмотреть в сообщении, оно выглядит наподобие «warning CS1234»)

```
#pragma warning disable 1234, 9876
// тут ваш код, генерирующий предупреждение
#pragma warning restore 1234, 9876
```

Не забудьте добавить комментарий, в котором вы описываете, почему именно в данном месте предупреждение можно игнорировать: это поможет тем, кто будет через полгода читать ваш код (например, вам самому).

Comment: Подскажите как узнать коды предупреждений, в списке ошибок только "описание", "файл", "строка", "столбец", "проект". Поиск в "Гугле" по описанию осложняется, тем что в студии всё переведено на русский.

Comment: Попробовал не указывать код - работает. спасибо.

Comment: @3per: Ну он (код) же указывается в предупреждении, в самом начале!

Comment: Увы http://i.stack.imgur.com/xSW7M.png VS 2008 Rus

Comment: @3per: Вы не туда смотрите :) Смотрите в лог компиляции, в окошке Output.